# starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"driver\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n"

Tags: apache-spark, docker, spring-boot, dockerfile, minikube

## I have spring based based spark 2.3.0 application. I am trying to do spark submit on kubernetes(minikube).

I have Virtual Box with docker and minikube running.

`opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://192.168.99.101:8443 --name cfe2 --deploy-mode cluster --class com.yyy.Application --conf spark.executor.instances=1 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=docker.io/anantpukale/spark_app:1.3 local://CashFlow-spark2.3.0-shaded.jar`

## Below is the stack trace:

```
 start time: N/A
 container images: N/A
 phase: Pending
 status: []
2018-04-11 09:57:52 INFO  LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl:54 - State changed, new state: 
     pod name: cfe2-c4f95aaeaefb3564b8106ad86e245457-driver
     namespace: default
     labels: spark-app-selector -&gt; spark-dab914d1d34b4ecd9b747708f667ec2b, spark-role -&gt; driver
     pod uid: cc3b39e1-3d6e-11e8-ab1d-080027fcb315
     creation time: 2018-04-11T09:57:51Z
     service account name: default
     volumes: default-token-v48xb
     node name: minikube
     start time: 2018-04-11T09:57:51Z
     container images: docker.io/anantpukale/spark_app:1.3
     phase: Pending
     status: [ContainerStatus(containerID=null, image=docker.io/anantpukale/spark_app:1.3, imageID=, lastState=ContainerState(running=null, terminated=null, waiting=null, additionalProperties={}), name=spark-kubernetes-driver, ready=false, restartCount=0, state=ContainerState(running=null, terminated=null, waiting=ContainerStateWaiting(message=null, reason=ContainerCreating, additionalProperties={}), additionalProperties={}), additionalProperties={})]
2018-04-11 09:57:52 INFO  Client:54 - Waiting for application cfe2 to finish...
2018-04-11 09:57:52 INFO  LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl:54 - State changed, new state: 
     pod name: cfe2-c4f95aaeaefb3564b8106ad86e245457-driver
     namespace: default
     labels: spark-app-selector -&gt; spark-dab914d1d34b4ecd9b747708f667ec2b, spark-role -&gt; driver
     pod uid: cc3b39e1-3d6e-11e8-ab1d-080027fcb315
     creation time: 2018-04-11T09:57:51Z
     service account name: default
     volumes: default-token-v48xb
     node name: minikube
     start time: 2018-04-11T09:57:51Z
     container images: anantpukale/spark_app:1.3
     phase: Failed
     status: [ContainerStatus(containerID=docker://40eae507eb9b615d3dd44349e936471157428259f583ec6a8ba3bd99d80b013e, image=anantpukale/spark_app:1.3, imageID=docker-pullable://anantpukale/spark_app@sha256:f61b3ef65c727a3ebd8a28362837c0bc90649778b668f78b6a33b7c0ce715227, lastState=ContainerState(running=null, terminated=null, waiting=null, additionalProperties={}), name=spark-kubernetes-driver, ready=false, restartCount=0, state=ContainerState(running=null, terminated=ContainerStateTerminated(containerID=docker://40eae507eb9b615d3dd44349e936471157428259f583ec6a8ba3bd99d80b013e, exitCode=127, finishedAt=Time(time=2018-04-11T09:57:52Z, additionalProperties={}), message=invalid header field value **"oci runtime error:  container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"driver\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n"**, reason=ContainerCannotRun, signal=null, startedAt=Time(time=2018-04-11T09:57:52Z, additionalProperties={}), additionalProperties={}), waiting=null, additionalProperties={}), additionalProperties={})] 
2018-04-11 09:57:52 INFO  LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl:54 - Container final statuses:
     Container name: spark-kubernetes-driver
     Container image: anantpukale/spark_app:1.3
     Container state: Terminated
     Exit code: 127
2018-04-11 09:57:52 INFO  Client:54 - Application cfe2 finished.
2018-04-11 09:57:52 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2018-04-11 09:57:52 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-d5813d6e-a4af-4bf6-b1fc-dc43c75cd643
```

## Below is image of my docker file.

Error trace suggest that something in docker i have triggered with command "docker".
[dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d5Dm.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

I was running into this issue. It is related to the docker image ENTRYPOINT. In spark 2.3.0 when using Kubernetes there now is an example of a Dockerfile which uses a specific script in the ENTRYPOINT found in kubernetes/dockerfiles/. If the docker image doesn't use that specific script as the ENTRYPOINT then the container doesn't start up properly. [Spark Kubernetes Docker documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#docker-images)

Answer (score 0):

in you Dockerfile use `ENV PATH="/opt/spark/bin:${PATH}"` instead of your line.

Comment: I changed the above command as you suggest . Still same error persist .

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to login into the container using

```
#>docker run -it --rm docker.io/anantpukale/spark_app:1.3 sh
```

and try running the main program or command that you want to submit.
Based on this output we can try to investigate further .

Comment: Yes , I am able to make it up and running in docker with your above command in sh mode. But here i need to modilfy my command a bit . I was submitting my spark job to Kubernetes api server earlier now in local client mode.   `/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --master local --name cfe2 --deploy-mode client --class com.oracle.Application --conf spark.executor.instances=1 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=docker.io/anantpukale/spark_app:1.3 CashFlow-2.2.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar`

Comment: I am using minikube for kubernetes version 1.9.4

Answer (score 0):

along with @hichamx suggested changes with below code worked for me to overcome  **"exec: \"driver\"** issue.

```
spark-submit \
    --master k8s://http://127.0.0.1:8001 \
    --name cfe2 \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --class com.oracle.Test \
    --conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=docker/anantpukale/spark_app:1.1 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.container.image=docker.io/kubespark/spark-driver:v2.2.0-kubernetes-0.5.0 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.container.image=docker.io/kubespark/spark-executor:v2.2.0-kubernetes-0.5.0 \
    local://spark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Though this gave Error: Exit Code :127 and spark-kubernetes-driver terminated.